# $x$ has terminating decimal represantation

Tags: real-analysis, decimal-expansion

Hey to all mathematicians out there. I'm new here so please be gentle if i have made error or something.The problem is this : $x\in (0,1)$ has terminating decimals if there exist $m,n\in\mathbb N \bigcup \{0\} $, so that  $2^m5^nx$ is integer.
I can't find any solution to the problem. My only thought was that for this to happen m must be equal to n.

Comment: Consider $x=0.5$ then $2^1 \cdot 5^0 \cdot x = 1$ so the powers don't need to be the same (though you can choose them to).

Comment: thank you for your answer, but is it the same if $x\in (0,1)$ ? i made an error when i was writing the problem

Comment: Let $m=n$.  Then we have $10^nx\in\mathbb N$.  What can you conclude about the decimal expansion of $10^nx$?

Comment: if we suppose that $x$ has a terminating decimal form then $10^nx$ is an integer. Excuse me but i don't  understand exactly what you are asking me or if i answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that if $2^m5^n x=p$ with $p\in\Bbb N$ and $2^m 5^n\in\Bbb N$ for $n,m\in\Bbb N$, then we have that $x=p/(2^m 5^n)$.

If you want that $x\in (0,1)$ then:

- First choose any $n,m\in\Bbb N$
- After choose some $p\in\Bbb N$ distinct of zero such that $p<2^m 5^n$

Under these conditions you have the desired $x\in(0,1)$ with terminating decimals.